# How to activate the API in Pootle 2.8.2

Tags: apache-2.4, django, mod-wsgi

I'm wondering does the Pootle API work the same in version 2.8.2 as in version 2.5.1? I don't see any updated docs for the API in Pootle 2.8.2, the last I see is https://pootle.readthedocs.io/en/stable-2.5.1/api/index.html

I have followed the same instructions as per Pootle 2.5.1, I installed **`django-tastypie`** , I added **`POOTLE_ENABLE_API = True`** in the **`pootle.conf`**, and I enabled **`WSGIPassAuthorization On`** in my apache virtual host configuration (and I restarted the apache server).

However if I try to make a GET request to **`https://my-pootle-server/api/v1/translation-projects/1/`** I simply get a 404 page not found error. I thought that a minimum amount of API requests were supposed to work out of the box? Or do I have to do more configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not receiving much feedback either here from serverfault or from the pootle mailing list makes me think that the Pootle project is at a standstill, doesn't seem to be actively developed at the moment. Considering the [last message on the public archive of the mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/translate/mailman/translate-pootle/?viewmonth=201803) is from March 2018, wow that's 10 months :o

I did find a channel where someone actually responded, I followed the link from the github repository's README. And there I am told that the [Pootle API was dropped somewhere around version 2.6](https://gitter.im/translate/pootle?at=5c4cae2e8aa5ca5abf374204) :o Well, that makes Pootle that much less useful... I guess I'll just start looking into weblate or some other alternative...